# Gem does not load over config.ru

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger, require

I have my own gem "RocketRuby". I loaded it in irb and it worked loading it. In earlyer versions I had it also in my config.ru and it worked.

Now I compiled it again and installed it again. Then (it's still working by loading it in irb) passenger crashes and tells me:

```
cannot load such file -- rocketruby (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `eval'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `preload_app'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:127:in `<module:App>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:6:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

The config.ru looks like this:

```
require "rocketruby"
require "./shop_of_one.rb"

ShopOfOne.instance

run RocketRuby::RackApplication.new
```

The very strange thing is, while this error comes, in irb `require "rocketruby"` still does work.

Any help?

Comment: What user is your application running as? You can see that in the Phusion Passenger error page. Is running user what you expect it to be? Also check your Ruby load path on that error page. Is it what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Passenger runs as it's own user, and doesn't share the environment even of the `apache` user it's loaded with. That means your gems are probably not installed when it tries to run.

Using bundler will solve this, I'm sure there are other ways, but adding a Gemfile, running `bundle install --deployment` and adding this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require
```

to the top of your rack app will solve the issue.